# How to dynamically change jquery mobile page theme without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile applies different class names on elements based on data-theme attribute when a page is initially loaded: like adding 'ui-bar-a' to a bar if data-theme='a'.

I want to dynamically change the theme on a JQM page, without reloading the page itself, like what JQM themeroller does: http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/?ver=1.3.2

But changing the data-theme attribute doesn't trigger the theme switch, JQM javascript still needs to redo what it does at initial page load.
How to trigger jquery mobile to rerender the page? I looked at documentation but didn't find any API for this.

Relevant question:
[Dynamically changing theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510043/dynamically-changing-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the triggering logic on page load and just remove and set classes yourself.

```
$(element).removeClass('ui-bar-a').addClass('ui-foo-b');
```

Comment: That will work. But the solution is ugly, every time I add some widgets to the page, I need to remember to add a line of theme code for it. I think things like switching a theme should be the framework's job.